# A complex function that is real valued on a set $A\subseteq \Bbb R$ where $A$ has an accumulation point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function satisfing $f(A)\subseteq \Bbb R,$ for some $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ which $A$ has an accumulation point. I want to show that $f(\Bbb R) \subseteq \Bbb R.$

with many thanks.

Comment: Look up: Schwarz Reflection Principle.

Comment: **Hint:** $f(z)-\overline{f(\overline{z})}=0$ on $A$ and $f(z)-\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is analytic

Answer (score 0):

I assume $f$ is analytic on an open set containing $\mathbb {R}.$ The hypotheses tell us $\operatorname {Im} f$ equals $0$ on $A.$ But $\operatorname {Im} f$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}.$ Since $A$ has an accumulation point in $\mathbb {R},$ we therefore have $\operatorname {Im} f\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb {R}.$ Hence $f$ is real-valued on $\mathbb {R}.$

Comment: Why we can say "$Im f $ equals 0 on A"? According to the assumptions $Im f \subseteq \Bbb R. $

Comment: You don't understand why $\text {Im} f = 0$ on $A$?

Comment: This is wrong. As an example for $f(z) = \sin(z)$ and $A = \Bbb R.$

Comment: This is a strange conversation. By $\text {Im} f$ I mean the imaginary part of  $ f.$ Because $f$ is real on $A,$  $\text {Im} f =0$ on $A.$ Are we OK?